# PHP logical key/value array separators

Tags: php, arrays

I am required to add support for allowing people to create basic primary arrays (no secondary e.g. multi-dimensional arrays).

In the (X)HTML text form I figure I should `explode` in to arrays using commas and semi-colons as key,value;key,value; pairs. Is this intuitive for other developers if they needed to store an array and if not what separators would you use?

Comment: What do you mean by "allowing people to create [..] arrays "?

Comment: How about `foo=bar&bar=baz`?

Comment: @Jack Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat natural way of encoding this (for developers at least) is to apply URL-encoding:

```
key1=value&key2=value
```

On the server side, you can then use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str) to decode it.

Comment: Whoa, nice find with `parse_str()`! That'll save me the small hassle of `explode`s and `trim`s. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[serialize()](http://php.net/serialize) might be your friend. This gives you a string representation of your array in a format that is standardized in PHP. The string can be re-converted to an array using `unserialize()`.

The output is human readable, but not very intuitive. If you need to exchange data between different programming languages, consider JSON.

Comment: You're talking about PHP, I'm talking about what someone types in to an (X)HTML text input element.